# How do I view contents of Android(4.1.2) folders on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, filemanager, usb-drive

Hello AskUbuntu Community! I am hoping you will be able to help me, or help me help you help me! I am trying to access my music stored on the external MicroSD card on my Samsung Android SGH-T699 via usb.

When I connect the phone to usb port, I get the pop up "Unable to mount Samsung Android SGH-T699" "Error initializing camera:-60:Could not lock the device." I just hit okay, and I can still view the folders on both the phone, and the ext_sd.

When I click on a folder, it goes into the directory, but does not display any of it the contents that are in it. Now a couple of weeks ago, I was able to put music on my phone, and read and write onto it (even with the error pop-up) just fine. Then I got an update, and it now it will not display any of the contents of the phone, or SD card.

Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried a google search. Many people seemed to have similar problems with their phone and Ubuntu. Their solutions, either did not work, or they had a different version with different options. Like ICS vs JellyBean.

1. Android developer options, USB Debugging.
2. Debian OS and same problem. I do not have any other computer to try, and no other OSes installed.
3. listing with hidden view enabled.

Let me know if you need more information. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I switched to Lubuntu 13.04 and now my android, and OS effortlessly work perfectly!
This is for a Compaq nx6325 notebook.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to switch on USB Mass Storage. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S2 running stock Android 4.1.2 and I have Ubuntu 13.04 on my desktop box.

The answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/197062/40242 describes how you can simply enable USB Mass Storage mode.

Comment: I own a Samsung Galaxy S Relay 4G with stock 4.1.2, the USB Mass Storage option is not present unless I connect phone via USB to the laptop. I get to options in the notification area. There are no settings for Storage in settings file unfortunately. Lubuntu 13 is working like a charm though, and probably the latest Ubuntu. Unfortunately My laptop only supported upto 10.04, as it failed on getting Unity to work, and was slow :( Thank you for the suggestion though!